# Nested ui-grid (grid inside cellTemplate)

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid, angular-ui-grid

I'm preparing a grid which have a column that contain another grid, i tried it with ngGrid it works according to this plunkr link :

```
    $scope.updateGrid = function() {$scope.gridOptions = {
    data: 'facdata',
      rowHeight: $scope.fac1data.length * $scope.rowHeight,
      columnDefs: [
        {field: 'examname',displayName: 'Exam Name'},
        {field: '', displayName: 'Subjects' , cellTemplate: '<div  ng-grid="gridOptions1"  ></div>'
      }]
    };
  }
```

[Plunkr link](http://plnkr.co/edit/wSd880e7cm2BlOkfdrAW?p=preview)

The previous link was done with ngGrid But when i tried to prepare the equivalent of this using ui-grid,
i got a problem (a.uiGrid is undefined).

Please help me for this issue
thanks

Comment: If you want to access any variable from your grid's template, you have to take the help of external-scope because ui-grid uses isolated scopes.
please have a look at http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/305_externalScopes

Comment: @user3114642 : Can you provide a working plunkr link.

Answer (score 2):

You can refer to this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/keLHObnxpaFfasyCQRNH?p=preview) link, it might help you...

you need to set another ui-grid in cellTemplate of a column, if u want to put it in a column.

```
 $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs = [
{name: 'id'},
{name: 'categoryName'},
{name: 'products', cellTemplate: '<div ui-grid="row.entity[\'products\']"></div>'} ];
```